# Fast way to get all yellow cells in range

Tags: excel, vba

I was wondering if there was a quick trick to get all yellows cells from a certain column in a range, for example for this example the range would be `A4:A7 + A11:A12 + A14` :

[image]

Is the only way by using a loop ?

Comment: Filter by color?

Comment: @BigBen Can the filter return be stored inside a range in order to use `WorksheetFunction.Sum(Myrng)` ? If yes can you please me how ? Im quite unsure of how to do it

Comment: Using `Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`.

Comment: If those cells are colored by conditional formatting then you have the conditions to match the cells.

Comment: @SolarMike they aint

Comment: @BigBen I would rather avoid use of filter .. Is it the only way ?

Comment: That or a loop. You can filter and then unfilter though.

Comment: @BigBen there is no param either such as `xlCellTypeVisible` but in order to select certain type of cells ?

Comment: No, you are out of luck if you want to select by color. You can use `Find` with `SearchFormat` but you'd still have to loop.

Comment: If you are very creative you can fidle around with `GET.CELL(38....)` in your name manager. Yet I don't see any benefits comming from that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the next code, please:

```
Sub testYellowCellsRange()
   'it needs a column header...
    Dim sh As Worksheet, rng As Range, rngF As Range, lastRow As Long, ret As String
    Set sh = ActiveSheet
    
    lastRow = sh.UsedRange.Rows.count
    Set rng = sh.Range("A1:A" & lastRow)
    rng.AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=RGB(255, 255, 0), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor
    Set rngF = rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    ret = Right(rngF.Address, Len(rngF.Address) - InStr(rngF.Address, ","))
     Debug.Print ret
    rng.AutoFilter
     sh.Range(ret).Select
End Sub
```

Comment: didn't try yet, i will give u feedback asap

Comment: @Dorian: Still testing...?

Comment: Yo just tested it and your code is amazing ! Thanks for your time